# Comparing two curves with different x-axis points - appropriate test?

Tags: regression, probability, matlab, nonlinear-regression

I have two curves and I want to be able to calculate the probability of these curves coming from different distributions or another appropriate statistic.

Each curve is fitted through the mean of clusters of data (x's and o's in diagram) at differing points on the x-axis, each data cluster is also non-parametrically distributed.

Is there a statistical test that would be appropriate to tell me how likely it is that the data/curves come from different distributions i.e. one is significantly different than the other?

```
        +   -         x
        |    o        ~
        |    -        x~
        |    o         ~
        |     -        ~~
        |     --        ~~
        |      -         ~
        |      --         ~~~
        |       -            ~~~
        |       -               ~~    x
        |        -o               ~~~ x
        |         -                  ~~ 
        |         o-                  x  ~ 
        |         o-                  x   ~ ~~             x
        |           --                        ~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~
        |            ----        o                         x
        |                - ----  o                         x
        |                      ----- ----               o
        |                        o       - ---- - -  - ---
        |                                               o
        |
        +----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I've looked here [Comparison of two curves](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74498/comparison-of-two-curves) but I believe my problem has some distinct differences

Comment: About all you are assuming, implicitly, seems to be single-valued curves (i.e. for each $x$, there is a single mean of $y$). So, I think the main, and possibly only, possibility is that you simulate drawing two groups randomly from your combined data, fit your curves and then do a kind of line-up comparing the "real" pattern and the simulated patterns. If the real pattern is genuine it will stand out from the others.

Comment: @Nick Cox Thanks for the answer although I am not sure I fully understand. Are you suggesting I create a simulated combined curve from both data sets and then use some test to see if the actual curves are different. What test would this be?

Comment: No; I am suggesting that you simulate drawing two curves repeatedly using the same methods. See http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~buja/PAPERS/06-Buja-Cook-Hofmann-Lawrence-Lee-Swayne-Wickham.pdf for the flavour. Warnings: I can't see any scope for a plug-in or off-the-shelf test if the question is just "I have two curves: are they genuinely different?" which is no more a precise statistical question than "I have two friends: are they genuinely different?". However, there are newer ideas, as in the paper cited, but they usually require some custom programming.

Comment: @Nick Cox I understand now, thank you. I'm certainly no statistician but for the engineering work I do we typically phrase the question something like: "What is the probability that the two sets of data (curves in this case) are due to a genuine difference rather than noise"

Comment: I am not a statistician either, but there is no free lunch in statistics. You might have that question but it is very difficult to answer. It is not far from the ultimate vague question "are my data meaningful?".

Comment: I understand the problem is more complex for a curve than say two normal distributions but I don't think the underlying question is vague. I'm trying to establish with what confidence I can say one set of data points is likely to arise from the natural variability or noise of the other. Whether this is at multiple points or a single p-value for the whole curve

Comment: Sure, but you don't have a specification that you can write down that would lead to a P-value. The word "vague" is not meant to be abusive here, just a statement of fact. Simply, absent a model for the generating process, absent a confidence or significance procedure. Using statistical terminology like "confidence" or "noise" does not buy much, unfortunately. Imagine a child drawing wiggly lines on a sheet of paper. Are they the same or different? Not answerable without much more detail.

Comment: A more technical point is that you seem to be fuzzing together ideas on curves (relationships) and ideas on distributions.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are correct. I lack understanding on this topic and was hoping that this problem had a well defined test such as when comparing two normal/non-parametric distributions but it seems it is more complex. If the curves were to be approximated as straight lines and the data was spread across the x-axis are you aware of common test for this scenario?

Comment: Distributions are not "non-parametric"; that is a property of procedures, although we would be better off without the term. But yes, whether two straight lines are different is a standard regression problem to be attacked using indicator variables (a.k.a. dummy variables). You can test whether the level and/or slope are different. But shoehorning your problem into a quite different shape is a dubious undertaking.

Comment: I may just resort to using Wilcoxon rank-sum for each pair of data clusters I'm interested in at a time and determine if their medians are significantly (p<0.05) different given the distributions (maybe with Bonferroni's correction as multiple comparisons).

Comment: You **could** do that, but it's not just the multiple comparisons that may bite; the comparisons are not independent either. If you are willing to assume ordered effects, something like Jonckheere-Terpstra may make more sense.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of this test. I will proceed with due care!

Comment: Sorry; I don't think Jonckheere-Terpstra will help on second thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for the two sample [K-S test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

Matlab Stats toolbox has an implementation, [kstest2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest2.html):

> kstest2(x1,x2) returns a test decision for the null hypothesis that
>   the data in vectors x1 and x2 are from the same continuous
>   distribution, using the two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. The
>   alternative hypothesis is that x1 and x2 are from different continuous
>   distributions.

Comment: I'm unclear exactly how I would use this. Would the vectors be the fitted points from the curve or include the data clusters around the known points? Thanks.

Comment: I would use your raw data points as x1 and x2.  If kstest2 returns a 1, then the null hypothesis has been rejected, meaning that samples x1 and x2 are likely drawn from different "true" distributions.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that combining each cluster of data from each curve into a single distribution is necessarily an appropriate way to do the analysis, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about "combining" the data ... You've got two sets of data.  Each represents samples coming from some underlying distribution.  I understood your problem as wanting to test whether those two sets of samples come from the same underlying distribution, which K-S pretty much does.